# Android 10: Starting an Activity in the Background

Tags: android, android-10.0

I developed a calling app for Android, like voice calling in WhatsApp and Google Duo. I used Firebase messaging to notify the app for incoming calls. Upon receiving an incoming call notification, the app starts a calling activity, that alerts the user for the incoming call. Using this activity, the user can either answer or reject the call. The app was working fine prior to Android 10. After Android 10 and the restrictions introduced with it, particularly the one that prevents apps in the background from starting activities, my app stopped working properly. This happened because I start the calling activity from the background which is not supported anymore. I saw that other voice calling apps (WhatsApp, Google Duo, and FB Messenger) have already adapted for this change. The issue is that I couldn't find any alternative to showing the calling activity. Can anyone give me a clue how to achieve this?

Comment: Use a high-priority notification with a full-screen `Intent` pointing at your desired activity. This will allow the user to respond to your incoming call, either via your activity (if there screen was locked) or your notification (if the screen was unlocked).

Comment: @CommonsWare Yeah I'm aware of this. I just wanted to know how Google Duo is still able to open an activity from the background.

Comment: @m2008m1033m found any solution ?